# Populate connections upon startup in Sequelize connection pool

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Node project which uses MySQL as the backend database. I have set up Sequelize as the ORM and have set up connection pooling in the constructor as below.

```
const sequelizeConfig = new Sequelize(DBConfig.config.name, DBConfig.config.user, DBConfig.config.pass, {
            dialect: 'mysql',
            host: 'mydbhost.com',
            pool: {
                max: 50,
                min: 20,
            },
            port: 3306,
            define: {
                timestamps: false,
                freezeTableName: true
            }
        });
```

However, this config is still creating new connections upon each request rather than fetching existing connections from the pool. I am testing the existing connections through the following SQL query.

```
show status where variable_name = 'threads_connected';
```

I get a static number of connections (2) when I run this query irrespective of what config I set in the min and max for the pool.

Is there anything which I am missing or is this something which Sequelize does not provide for?

Comment: Try increasing the  eviction time `options.pool.evict` (defaults to 1 second) to see if they hang around. I'm not sure of the behavior of sequelize pools, I would have thought connections would be lazily created. It doesn't make sense to create them up front and then evict them after an idle timeout.

Comment: Doesn't work. I am actually porting a legacy Java app which does utilize this approach since there is a lot of load and connection creation is expensive. In any case, I am just seeing 2 connections active upon startup to a period of around 30s.